# The problem of using session in a while loop

Tags: php, session

```
 <?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
@session_start();
while(1)
{
    @session_start();
    $_SESSION["xxx"]="222";
    session_write_close();
    sleep(3);
    @session_start();
    $_SESSION["xxx"]="111";
    session_write_close();
}?>
```

As shown above,I keep changing $_SESSION["xxx"]'s value in the while loop.
but i find the session file is always`xxx|s:3:"222";`

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of this code, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear why you care about this or what benefit you think it would have.

Comment: i tested this project,```https://github.com/L-codes/Neo-reGeorg````,in this project tunnel.php “connect” case  use session save write buf and read buf,but When I was using it, I found that the session value was not correctly retrieved when other requests went through.

Comment: The value of session["xxx"] that is modified in the loop should be correctly retrieved when other requests come in, but when I tested it, I found that session["xxx"]is always 222.